# Compute standard Deviation of pandas dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am currently working on a Machine Learning model and I am in the process of feature engineering. I am using a dataset that indicates the number of product sales of 70+ items across 13 stores.

I have created features such as the average price of an item based on its SKU-ID (what product it is). I now wish to make a feature of the standard deviation for each SKU price.

Following is the function I used for generating the average price of a particular product across all stores as well as my function for determining the standard deviation of a product's price across all stores:

```
 def gen_average_price(train,test,col,price='base_price',name='name'):
    temp=train.groupby(col)[price].mean().reset_index().rename(columns={price:name})
    train=pd.merge(train,temp,how='left',on=col)
    test=pd.merge(test,temp,how='left',on=col)
    train[name].fillna(np.median(temp[name]),inplace=True)
    test[name].fillna(np.median(temp[name]),inplace=True)
    return train,test

 def gen_std_price(train,test,col,price='base_price',name='name'):
    temp=train.groupby(col)[price].mean().reset_index().rename(columns={price:name})
    train=pd.merge(train,temp,how='left',on=col)
    test=pd.merge(test,temp,how='left',on=col)
    s = np.median(temp[name])
    train[name].fillna(statistics.stdev(s), inplace = True)
    test[name].fillna(statistics.stdev(s), inplace = True)
    return train,test
```

This is the function i use to obtain the average price for a specific product as well as the funtion to obtain the standard deviation of a product's price. The average price function (gen_average_price) above works as intended, however when i attempt to use my standard deviation function for obtaining the standard deviation of a product's price i run in to the following error:

```
#Generating std dev of prices per sku-id
train,test = gen_std_price(train,test,col=['sku_id'],price='base_price',name='price_sku_id_stdev') 

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Can anyone help me as to why this is the case and/or how to fix it?

Following is some more info on the datasets used:

```
train.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 150150 entries, 0 to 150149
Data columns (total 16 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------              --------------   -----  
 0   record_ID           150150 non-null  int64  
 1   week                150150 non-null  object 
 2   store_id            150150 non-null  int64  
 3   sku_id              150150 non-null  int64  
 4   total_price         150150 non-null  float64
 5   base_price          150150 non-null  float64
 6   is_featured_sku     150150 non-null  int64  
 7   is_display_sku      150150 non-null  int64  
 8   units_sold          150150 non-null  int64  
 9   count_id_sku_store  150150 non-null  float64
 10  count_id_sku        150150 non-null  float64
 11  count_id_store      150150 non-null  float64
 12  price_sku_store     150150 non-null  float64
 13  price_to_sku_store  150150 non-null  float64
 14  price_store_id      150150 non-null  float64
 15  price_sku_id        150150 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(9), int64(6), object(1)
memory usage: 19.5+ MB

test.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 13860 entries, 0 to 13859
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------              --------------  -----  
 0   record_ID           13860 non-null  int64  
 1   week                13860 non-null  object 
 2   store_id            13860 non-null  int64  
 3   sku_id              13860 non-null  int64  
 4   total_price         13860 non-null  float64
 5   base_price          13860 non-null  float64
 6   is_featured_sku     13860 non-null  int64  
 7   is_display_sku      13860 non-null  int64  
 8   count_id_sku_store  13860 non-null  float64
 9   count_id_sku        13860 non-null  float64
 10  count_id_store      13860 non-null  float64
 11  price_sku_store     13860 non-null  float64
 12  price_to_sku_store  13860 non-null  float64
 13  price_store_id      13860 non-null  float64
 14  price_sku_id        13860 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(9), int64(5), object(1)
memory usage: 1.7+ MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an another approach, You can use `train.describe()` for the complete description of your dataset. It will return count, mean, standard deviation, median, 1st quartile, 3rd quartile and maximum value.

**EXAMPLE**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(0,10),"b":range(10,20)})
df.describe()
```

[image]